# matplotlib scatter plot np.choose Value error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am doing kmeans and trying to plot multiple clusters.

I have the following code, where X is my data points array:

```
centroids, ks = kmeans2(X,3) 
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=np.choose(ks, colors))
plt.show()
```

When trying to plot with 3 clusters, everything is fine[image]

When trying to plot compute 4 clusters, I get an error saying:

```
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=np.choose(ks, colors))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 297, in choose
    return choose(choices, out=out, mode=mode)
ValueError: invalid entry in choice array
```

Comment: With 4 groups, shouldn't you need 4 colors? like `colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k']`?

Comment: Great comment! Do you know how I would be able to have many colors? Say I would like to have 50 clusters?

Comment: To long for a comment, see the following answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have at least `n` colors for `n` groups. I will suggest using `Paired` colormap, when you have a large number of groups and you want different groups to have different colors:

```
In [223]:
#An example of generation 10 different colors.
import matplotlib.cm as cmap
cmap.Paired(np.linspace(0,1,10)) #returns rgba values for 10 different colors.
Out[223]:
array([[ 0.65098041,  0.80784315,  0.89019608,  1.        ],
       [ 0.24138409,  0.55454056,  0.67164939,  1.        ],
       [ 0.49101116,  0.77181086,  0.38794312,  1.        ],
       [ 0.72287582,  0.61176473,  0.45751636,  1.        ],
       [ 0.90200693,  0.16495195,  0.17131873,  1.        ],
       [ 0.9931411 ,  0.71752404,  0.38066898,  1.        ],
       [ 0.93071896,  0.56470589,  0.27973857,  1.        ],
       [ 0.57217994,  0.42994234,  0.70173012,  1.        ],
       [ 0.8785544 ,  0.8418762 ,  0.60081509,  1.        ],
       [ 0.69411767,  0.34901962,  0.15686275,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you. One question however, I get an error on line     plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=np.choose(ks, colors)), on the choose method

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: I remember `ks` should be a 1D `array` of `int`, in that case, replacing `c=np.choose(ks, colors)` with `colors[ks]` should fix it.